# Rubymotion UIView Orientation

Tags: ios7, rubymotion

I currently have an ios app that I am writing in Rubymotion. I am trying to setup a UIViewController to display in portrait orientation always and not rotate to landscape. I cannot only specify portrait orientation in my rakefile as I need all orientaitons for other uiviewcontrollers. See below for my code:

```
class ConfirmationController < UIViewController

def viewDidLoad
    super
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor
end

def shouldAutorotate
  true
end

def supportedInterfaceOrientations
  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait
end

def preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait
end
```

As you can see I am trying to set my preferredInterfaceOrientation but it is still changing to a landscape orientation when my device is rotated. Any ideas on how to set this up with Rubymotion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing research I found where the issue came from was the UINavigationController being the rootView. I had to add a named controller that inherited from UINavigationController and then override the default UINavigation settings to change according to topViewController.

**AppDelegate.rb**

```
class TopNavController < UINavigationController

  def supportedInterfaceOrientations
    self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations
  end

  def preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    self.topViewController.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
  end
end

main_controller = MainScreenController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle: nil)
@window.rootViewController= TopNavController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(main_controller)
```

**UIViewController**

```
def shouldAutorotate
  true
end

def supportedInterfaceOrientations
  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight
end

def preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
  UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
end
```

Answer (score 3):

From [Rubymotion developer center](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/project-management/):

> Supported interface orientations. Value must be an Array of one or more of the following symbols: :portrait, :landscape_left, :landscape_right, and :portrait_upside_down. The default value is [:portrait, :landscape_left, :landscape_right].

If you need to lock the orientation in landscape for the whole app, you can set the `interface_orientations` in your Rakefile, under

```
Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  app.name = 'Awesome App'
  app.interface_orientations = [:landscape_left,:landscape_right]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`preferredInterfaceOrientation` is not a property, it's a method that you have to implement, to change the behaviour of your view.

So, you should remove the line that sets `preferredInterfaceOrientation` and add something like this in your ViewController:

```ruby
class ConfirmationController < UIViewController
    ...
    ...

    def supportedInterfaceOrientations
        UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape
    end

    def preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
        UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
    end

    ...
    ...
end
```

For details on how this works, have a look at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)